# Android keyboard covers elements on web form

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, forms

I have a simple HTML form where the input elements (text boxes) are centered on the page. Problem is on mobile devices (specifically Android) when the keyboard comes up, it covers some of these elements. Even when I tap next while filling out the form, the page doesn't scroll to reveal the hidden elements. Any suggestions? Is there some JavaScript or CSS that I can add?

Answer (score 2):

Try using onfocus javascript event. If You use JQuery, you can use this sample, which, if device is touch screen device, scrolls input to very top of viewport on every input focus event.

```
function isTouchDevice() {  
  try {  
    document.createEvent("TouchEvent");  
    return true;  
  } catch (e) {  
    return false;  
  }  
}

$("input").focus(function(){
    if( isTouchDevice() ){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
})
```